# Linking html to php with $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to create a form that reads a post from an HTML form and displays an element from that post IF it detects that the post exists.
However, each time the post is submitted, it simply reloads the form as though no post were provided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload from Manifest</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['manifest'])) {
    echo 'we are in the IF';
    echo($_POST['manifest']);
}
?>


        <h1>Submission from manifest into main db</h1>
        <div class="container offset-top120">
            <form method="post" action="https://nhsggc.cogiva.com/prism/loadFromManifest.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="manifest" type="text" />
                <input id="submit" value="Submit" type = "submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: learn html ... so get an request manifest your input must have the **name** manifest

Comment: You need to use the `name` attribute on your form fields in addition to, or instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is going to either a different page (`https://nhsggc.cogiva.com/prism/loadFromManifest.php` so check for that first)  if you wanted it to go to same page, you can give the action as just '#', or put in the whole URL like you have.

You're missing the `name` attribute from your `submit` input and `text` input. Read up on the `name` attribute!

```
<input id="manifest" type="text" name="manifest">
<input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" name='submit' />
```

Then your PHP should look like this:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'Inside an if';
    echo $_POST['manifest'];
  }
```

Then it *should* work.

Comment: He will need to put a name on the text field too to access that value.

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking! I only wrote out half my answer too! Thanks @AntonyD'Andrea